# PHP use standard functions

Tags: php, namespaces, phpstorm, standard-library

I always used standard php lib functions without any `use` statement as this is the right way to do so and I am certain of it. 
However recently I updated my PhpStorm and now it automatically autocompletes any standard function (like `var_dump`, `array_fill` etc) with `use`. This is an example:

```
use function array_fill;
use function array_key_exists;
use function var_dump;

$x = array_fill(0, 5, 'a');
var_dump($x);
```

Is there any reason behind this? Obviously, it works fine with or without these `use`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your auto import settings for PHP in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Auto Import`.

In particular -- `Enable auto-import from the global namespace` option -- looks like it's enabled on your setup.